# SQL Join tables multiply lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I use Microsoft SQL Server. I have a problem...

Test code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test1 
(
    link nvarchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #Test2
(
    Name nvarchar(max),
)

INSERT INTO #Test1
VALUES
    ('/http://bla-bla/Link+For+Test'),
    ('/http://bla-bla/Test+Link+For+Test'),
    ('/http://bla-bla/Test+Link+For+Test+Second'),
    ('/bla-bla%Link+For+Edited+Test'), 
    ('/bla-bla%2fFor+Test+Edited')

INSERT INTO #Test2
VALUES
    ('Link For Test')
    ,('Test Link For Test')
    ,('Link For Edited Test')
    ,('For Test Edited')

SELECT
    RIGHT((REPLACE(t1.link, '+', ' ')), LEN(t2.[Name])) AS NameFromLink,
    t2.name,
    t1.link
FROM
    #Test1 t1
INNER JOIN
    #Test2 t2 ON RIGHT(REPLACE(t1.link, '+', ' '), LEN(t2.[Name])) = t2.[Name]

DROP TABLE #Test1
DROP TABLE #Test2
```

the blue line is the problem.

[image]

**Explanation**: I have links in the first table, from where I need to get a name. This path is not always the same, so we can't relay on charindex with substring, so we decided to take a name from other table, and count LEN of it, and then connect with a path and take that amount of symbols from rights side.

The problem is - it works perfectly from the right side, but the left side, if there is some link that contains exact same name ( as it is in the example ), but with new letters before that name, it joins two times.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the path you need always the portion after the *last* `/`? Though, I must admit, the design is the more likely candidate to be the problem here.

Comment: unfortunately it is not :( sometimes it's just %, sometime / and so on(

Comment: Looks like you need to give more examples then with *all* of the possible variations. Though your comment seems to also further cement my suspicion, that the design is the problem.

Comment: It  could look like that
 ('/http://bla-bla%Test+Link+For+Test'),
 ('/http://bla-bla%2fTest+Link+For+Test+Second')
And who knows, how it will in the future, there no hope for good "design" (( that is why we hoped just to connect on name... we can't write million replace functions(

Comment: [Edit] your question.

Comment: added a few  lines in both tables

Answer (score 1):

*If* you know what the all the last characters can be, then you could use `PATINDEX` to get the right hand side of the value you need. If you don't, then fix the design, as you have already found the method you want isn't going to work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #Test1 T1
     LEFT JOIN #Test2 T2 ON REPLACE(RIGHT(T1.link,PATINDEX('%[/%]%',REVERSE('/' + T1.link))-1),'+',' ') = T2.Name;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wR4G6Z9S)

Comment: yeah, it seems like we would need smth else unfortinatly, cause like %2f part is not a part of the Name, and it is another part we need to replace, and may be smth else we will need to replace...It is epicor catalogue, it is pure pain ^( thank you very much for help anyways!!!